# Can we use emit function in outside of the EventHandler in BLOC?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I get this warning when I use `emit` function outside of EventHandler?

**The member 'emit' can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' or a test. (Documentation)**

Is there any problem if I use like this?

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  HomeBloc() : super(HomeInitial()) {
    on<OpenActivityEvent>((event, emit) {
      openSampleActivity(event.context);
    });
  }

  void emitState() {
   //The member 'emit' can only be used within 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart' or a test
    emit(HomeInitial());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an `Emitter` as parameter, you could achieve it like the following:

```
void emitState(Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    emit(HomeInitial());
}
```

You can then call the emit method this way.

```
on<OpenActivityEvent>((event, emit) {
  emitState(emit);
});
```

You can also do this

```
HomeBloc() : super(HomeInitial()) {
  on<OpenActivityEvent>(_onOpenActivityEvent);
}

void _onOpenActivityEvent(OpenActivityEvent event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
   emit(HomeInitial());
}
```

Comment: why don't we emit outside in the function? like the `emitState()` function in the question